# Convert PHP Array into usable variable

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to get my array values into a usable variable. I would like to output these values into something readable to that I can use them in a SELECT call for my next statement.  The final result I would like to be able to do something like echo $numresults and should look like this 9,8,6  My code as follows will out put the following using print_r as seen below.

```
Array ( [0] => 9 ) Array ( [0] => 8 ) Array ( [0] => 6 )
```

I feel like I am close but not sure how to get this array into a usable variable.

```
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {
    if ($rowa['Count'] > 0) {
        $cids[]= $rowa['id'];
        display_id($rowa['id'], $levela + 1);
    } elseif ($rowa['Count']==0) {
        $cids[]= $rowa['id'];
    }

}
print_r($cids);
```

Comment: Let me know if you need help with my answer

Comment: Both are really close however when using the rtrim, substr($string, 0, -1); mb_substr($string, 0, -1); function to remove the last , in the output it will remove all the commas and bring the output from 9,8,6, to 986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cids = "";

while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {
    if ($rowa['Count'] > 0)  {
        $cids = $cids . $rowa['id'] . ",";
        display_id($rowa['id'], $levela + 1);
    } elseif ($rowa['Count']==0) {
        $cids = $rowa['id'];
    }
}

print_r($cids);
```

Comment: Both are really close however when using the rtrim, substr($string, 0, -1); mb_substr($string, 0, -1); function to remove the last , in the output it will remove all the commas and bring the output from 9,8,6, to 986

Comment: Fixed it simply changed to $cids .",". $rowa['id']; from $cids . $rowa['id'] . ","; works perfect now